# Does someone know more about "Minecraft – Greek mythology edition"?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357072/171580) was asked about that game, but used the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag. I asked in the comments what that is and got [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/greek-mythology-mash-up/c1kbn0qdctzd?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab). Apparently this is some new Minecraft related game made by Microsoft.

Does someone know more about this? I would simply create a new tag for it (for example [minecraft-greek-mythology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-greek-mythology)), but I know absolutely nothing about this game, so I wouldn't know what to write into the tag wiki.

Comment: From the description it doesn't sound like a whole separate game, just like some objects and themes and stuff but I don't know enough about Minecraft to say for sure. I don't think it needs a whole tag, though.

Comment: What else would you tag that question with? [tag:minecraft] is definitely not correct, that's for a different game.

Comment: I feel that *"How does Minecraft Greek Edition differ from the base game?"* with the [tag:version-differences] tag would make a good main-site question. As for the tag, it kinda looks like and is priced like an official DLC or modpack, sooooo maybe?

Comment: But what would it be a DLC for or what would it modify? And, sure, ask that question, I'm not interested enough in this to ask that, I just wanted to get rid of the [tag:minecraft] tag on that question. :D

Comment: I note that the system requirements section of the link says "
Available on: 
Xbox One
", so you could at the very least retag it to [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition].

Comment: OK, done. But I doubt that it's actually that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minecraft Greek Mythology is a so called **Mashup Pack**:

> A mashup pack is a combination of Skin Pack, Texture Pack, and a Map
>   all rolled up into one. These have been common on Minecraft Console
>   Edition for years now. <sup>[source](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/2815150-what-are-these-mash-up-packs-in-the-mcpe-store)</sup>

In this case, it contains "Greek gods, fantastical creatures and epic locations", " a bespoke texture set and themed UI" and an "orchestral soundtrack".

Basically, it seems to be a DLC with an emphasis on appearance.

**It's currently also available for the Pocket and Windows 10 editions**. <sup>[source](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/greek-mythology-minecraft)</sup>

As it doesn't seem to change core elements, a retag might not be necessary (but I'm not very familiar with the do's and don'ts of tagging yet).

Comment: I'd say **keep** the bedrock tag, as it's for the **bedrock** version of the game.

Answer (score 5):

There are many resource packs available to download from the Minecraft marketplace. You can download character skins, texture packs, and maps. The Greek Mythology pack contains all three.

When you apply a texture pack to your world, everything looks different but still behaves the same. The person asking the question simply wants to know what texture the zombie villagers have when the Greek Mythology texture pack is applied. The behavior of a zombie and a zombie villager is the same, so if you don't know the difference between the textures you would have to use trial and error to figure out which is which, which can be annoying for what the poster is trying to do.

This is still Minecraft Bedrock edition and it doesn't need a new tag.